# Resolution lower then 800x600 on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, resolution

I need to set the screen resolution to 960x540px but the vertical resolution is lower than 600px, and is not supported since 8th May 2018. Windows doesn't see this resolution even if Radeon drivers accept it. Is there a way to bypass that?

I want to stack 2 monitors vertically to use them as one 960x1080px. Is there a way to set the game to go full screen on both of them?

Comment: Some graphics cards can combine 2 monitors to form one desktop of a higher resolution. That should work for you.

Comment: This sounds like a whole lot of "bad idea" going on.  If you are trying to increase frame rate, ask yourself how much processing/GPU power it is going to take to split one logical screen?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the free
[Custom Resolution Utility (CRU)](https://www.monitortests.com/forum/Thread-Custom-Resolution-Utility-CRU):

> Custom Resolution Utility (CRU) is an EDID editor with a focus on custom resolutions. CRU shows you how the monitor defines resolutions and other capabilities and gives you the power to change it. Add custom resolutions, remove unwanted resolutions, edit FreeSync ranges, and more.

You could also achieve the same via utilities from the manufacturer of your
video-card. The following article lists such methods for Intel, NVIDIA and AMD:
[How to Create Custom Resolutions on Windows 7, 8 or 10](https://appuals.com/how-to-create-custom-resolutions-on-windows-7-8-or-10/).

Comment: Seems like OP already tried this: "Windows doesn't see this resolution even if Radeon drivers accept it. Is there a way to bypass that?"

Comment: Yea. And I've also tried CRU already.

Comment: What happens with CRU? Normally it should work.

Comment: I can input 960x540 into CRU but Window's display settings doesn't see it. I tested this program with other resolutions like 1910x1070 or 960x600 and it works fine.

Comment: How do you know that the driver accepts this resolution? Why can't you use only one terminal at 960x1080px?

Comment: Graphics card is connected to multi viewer HDMI-QC-4/1 with 2 cables (1st HDMI-HDMI, 2nd DP-HDMI) and this device is seen by PC as 2 monitors.

Comment: CRU should work if the driver accepts the settings. The problem might be with the driver. Perhaps you can get by with two unequal screens, one higher than the other?

Answer (score 0):

Found solution.
AMD Eyefinity Mode merge my 2 monitors into 1 bigger, virtual that handle 960x1080. Each monitor gets 960x540 signal.
Full screen on both monitors also work almost perfectly.